# A POJO class which extends Serializable Interface is also called as POJO class?

Tags: java

```
class Sample implements Serializable 
{

// code

}
```

Now this Sample class is called as POJO..?

Comment: POJO stands for "plain old Java object".

Comment: "POJO" is really more of a buzzword than anything else, it's not an official standard of any kind. It's defined more in terms of what it's _not_ than what it is.

Answer (score 2):

No, according quoting wikipedia a plain old java object should not:
Ideally speaking, a POJO is a Java object not bound by any restriction other than those forced by the Java Language Specification; i.e. a POJO should not have extend prespecified classes, as in

```
public class Foo extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet { ...
```

Implement prespecified interfaces, as in

```
public class Bar implements javax.ejb.EntityBean { ...
```

Contain prespecified annotations, as in

```
@javax.persistence.Entity public class Baz { ...
```

See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object for further details.

Answer (score 0):

In computing based on the Java Platform, JavaBeans are classes that encapsulate many objects into a single object (the bean). They are serializable, have a zero-argument constructor, and allow access to properties using getter and setter methods
They are used to encapsulate many objects into a single object (the bean), so that they can be passed around as a single bean object instead of as multiple individual objects. A JavaBean is a Java Object that is serializable, has a 0-argument constructor, and allows access to properties using getter and setter methods.
A JavaBean is just a standard

```
All properties private (use getters/setters)
A public no-argument constructor
Implements Serializable.
```

POJO stands for Plain Old Java Object, and would be used to describe the same things as a "Normal Class" whereas a JavaBean follows a set of rules. Most commonly Beans use getters and setters to protect their member variables, which are typically set to private and have a no-argument public constructor.Hence a pojo which has getters and setter ,no arg constructor and implements serialisable is basically a javabean which can have its states saved and retreived from a file.

Comment: @suraj chennoju if thats ok you can give it a right tick